# Windows - sharing connection to WinTun interface - ping fails with protocol unreachable

Tags: windows, networking, ping, connection-sharing, icmp

I'm trying to access the network from the Windows app which creates TUN interface connection.

- Windows 10 Home Edition.
- TUN interface created with https://www.wintun.net/ project example code.
- When calling `ping -S 102.168.137.1 192.168.0.109`, ping finishes with success.
- Windows firewall is turned off.
- Windows network profile is `private network` (trusted network where computer may be discovered by others).
- **Problem**: When calling ping programmatically (sending bytes) through `WinTun` interface, an error occurs as described below.

There is following network structure:

[image: Network interface structure]

There is following ICMP packet flow:

- TUN Interface sends the ping packet to shared WiFi connection
- Shared WiFi changes the packet's source IP address (NAT?) and sends it to the Linux computer.
- Linux computer responds normally.
- Unexpectedly, the Windows 10 responds to Linux: `Destination Unreachable (Protocol unreachable)`.
- I've expected that Windows 10 will perform backward translation of IP address and forward it to the TUN interface.

### Details

#### ICMP Packets

- Ping request (Windows to Linux) [packet analysis](https://hpd.gasmi.net/?data=144f8ab3be0bb46d839a069608004500001c00000000fd013bbfc0a80064c0a8006d0800f6ff01000000) 144f8ab3be0bb46d839a069608004500001c00000000fd013bbfc0a80064c0a8006d0800f6ff01000000
- Ping replay (Linux to Windows) [packet analysis](https://hpd.gasmi.net/?data=b46d839a0696144f8ab3be0b08004500001c18d100004001dfeec0a8006dc0a800640000feff01000000)
  b46d839a0696144f8ab3be0b08004500001c18d100004001dfeec0a8006dc0a800640000feff01000000
- ICMP error packet - `Destination unreachable (Protocol unreachable)` (Windows to Linux) [packet analysis](https://hpd.gasmi.net/?data=144f8ab3be0bb46d839a069608004500003800b400008001b7efc0a80064c0a8006d0302fcfd000000004500001c18d100003f015851c0a8006dc0a889010000000000000000)
  144f8ab3be0bb46d839a069608004500003800b400008001b7efc0a80064c0a8006d0302fcfd000000004500001c18d100003f015851c0a8006dc0a889010000000000000000

#### Windows ip and route configuration (not changed manually)

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Unknown adapter Demo:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::219f:2800:9778:a5e3%8
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.137.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Wireless LAN adapter PoÅ‚Ä…czenie lokalne* 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter PoÅ‚Ä…czenie lokalne* 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::86ac:ff4b:556a:dc0d%14
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.100
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1



C:\WINDOWS\system32>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 13...50 7b 9d 2f 13 80 ......Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
  8...........................Example Tunnel
 15...b4 6d 83 9a 06 97 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
 24...b6 6d 83 9a 06 96 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #3
 14...b4 6d 83 9a 06 96 ......Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1    192.168.0.100     55
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.0.100    311
    192.168.0.100  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.100    311
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.100    311
    192.168.137.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.137.1    261
    192.168.137.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.137.1    261
  192.168.137.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.137.1    261
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.0.100    311
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.137.1    261
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.100    311
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.137.1    261
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
 14    311 fe80::/64                On-link
  8    261 fe80::/64                On-link
  8    261 fe80::219f:2800:9778:a5e3/128
                                    On-link
 14    311 fe80::86ac:ff4b:556a:dc0d/128
                                    On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
 14    311 ff00::/8                 On-link
  8    261 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

### My questions:

- Why Windows responds with ping error and how to make it working?
- Does Windows use NAT when sharing internet connection?

*Thank you for your attention. Any comments and tips will be appreciated.*